# opengles 2.0 error 1282 after call glDrawElements(...) method

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I have some troubles with opengles 2.0. Currently I trying to display 3D teapot model without success. Method GLES20.glDrawElements generate opengl error with number 1282 and nothing is displayed on screen.

My draw method code:

```
public void draw(float[] tfMVPMatrix) {
    GLES20.glUseProgram(miProgramID);
    miVertexPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(miProgramID, VertexShader.Variables.VERTEX_POSITION.getName());
    miVertexTexCoordsHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(miProgramID, VertexShader.Variables.VERTEX_TEXTURE_CORDS.getName());
    miVertexNormalsHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(miProgramID, VertexShader.Variables.VERTEX_NORMALS.getName());
    miProjectionMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(miProgramID, VertexShader.Variables.MVP_MATRIX.getName());
    miColorHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(miProgramID, FragmentShader.Variables.COLOR.getName());
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(miVertexPositionHandle);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(miProgramID, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 3 * Float.SIZE, moVertBuff);

    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(miVertexTexCoordsHandle);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(miProgramID, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 2 * Float.SIZE, moTexCoordBuff);

    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(miVertexNormalsHandle);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(miProgramID, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 3 * Float.SIZE, moNormBuff);

    GLES20.glUniform4fv(miColorHandle, 1, COLOR, 0);
    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(miProjectionMatrixHandle, 1, false, tfMVPMatrix, 0);

    GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, miIndicesNumber, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, moIndBuff); // opengl error 1282

    GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(miVertexPositionHandle);
    GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(miVertexTexCoordsHandle);
    GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(miVertexNormalsHandle);
}
```

Vertex shader code:

```
attribute vec4 vPosition;
attribute vec4 vNormal;
attribute vec2 vTexture;
varying vec2 texCoord;
varying vec4 normal;
uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;
void main() {
    gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * vPosition;
    normal = vNormal;
    texCoord = vTexture;
}
```

Fragment shader code:

```
precision mediump float;
varying vec4 normal;
uniform vec4 vColor;
void main() {
    gl_FragColor = vColor;
    }
```

My renderer code:

```
public class MyRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {
private int GLProgramID;
private Demo3DObj oDemoTeapot;
private final float[] mMVPMatrix = new float[16];
private final float[] mProjectionMatrix = new float[16];
private final float[] mViewMatrix = new float[16];
private float fRatio;

@Override
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
    GLProgram oProgram = new GLProgram();
    GLProgramID = oProgram.build();
    oDemoTeapot = new Demo3DObj(GLProgramID);
    GLES20.glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
}

@Override
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
    GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    fRatio = (float)width/height;
    Matrix.frustumM(mProjectionMatrix, 0, -fRatio, fRatio, -1, 1, 3, 7);
}

@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    Matrix.setLookAtM(mViewMatrix, 0, 0, 0, -3, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mProjectionMatrix, 0, mViewMatrix, 0);
    GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    oDemoTeapot.draw(mMVPMatrix);
}
}
```

I'm new in opengles world and I do not have any idea what can be wrong here. Can anybody help me solve this problem? What should I change here to display my model?

UPDATE!

Here is method, which is used to create moIndBuff:

```
private Buffer fillBufferI(int[] oContainer) {
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(2 * oContainer.length);
    bb.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
    for (int s : oContainer)
        bb.putInt(s);
    bb.rewind();
    return bb;
}
```

Comment: For info, 1282 is 0x0502 in hex, which corresponds to GL_INVALID_OPERATION error code. See [here](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glDrawElements.xhtml) for the meaning.

Could you also show the code you use to create moIndBuff ?

Comment: So if i good understand, data type for my buffer container "moIndBuff" can be wrong? I tried to change from int to short.. Still blank screen. I added code which i use to create moIndBuff inside first post